# Can the new DriveApp parameters be used to search a specific folder?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for a way to search a specific folder using DriveApp in Google Apps Script. Here is what I have tried:

```
var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById('searchedFolderId');
var results = folders.searchFolders( "title contains '"+searchTerm+"'");
while (results.hasNext()) {   
var folder = results.next();
// do something with search results here
}
```

Whenever I try this method, I only get the first folder found returned in the folder iterator even though there are many other results.

I have also tried:

```
var results = DriveApp.searchFolders( "'searchedFolderId' in parents and title contains '"+searchTerm+"'");
```

Now, whenever I try this method, I sometimes get more than one found folder returned in the folder iterator. Is there a way to search a specific folder using the DriveApp API...am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was working. I had some nested folders that were not getting checked.

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure:

```
A
|-> B
|-> C
|-> D
```

The following code may be helpful.

```js
...
var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById('****************************'); // ID A
var folders = parent.getFolders(); 
while (folders.hasNext()) {
  var folder = folders.next();
  Logger.log(folder.getName());  
}

var specificFolder = parent.getFoldersByName('C');
if(specificFolder.hasNext())
  Logger.log(specificFolder.next().getName());
...
```

To search a specific folder you can use the method: [`getFoldersByName(name)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder?hl=en#getFoldersByName%28String%29).

**UPDATE**

Indeed you can not use [searchFolders(params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder?hl=en#searchFolders%28String%29) with `parent.getFolders()` because [getFolders()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder?hl=en#getFolders%28%29) returns a [FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator.html), however, you can use `parent.searchFolders(params)` to search internally in `parent`.

Comment: I want to search by a variety of parameters and not the exact name. That would seem to be a good solution if I could use .searchFolders() with parent.getFolders(), but it seems that I cannot. Maybe I need to use find, but that is so slow compared to the native DriveApp functions.